# passing an array of string using json

Tags: android, arrays, json

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
jsonObj.put("email", email);
jsonObj.put("password", password);
// Create the POST object and add the parameters
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("http://api.readfa.st/session");
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(jsonObj.toString(), HTTP.UTF_8);
entity.setContentType("application/json");
httpPost.setEntity(entity);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);`
```

Currently I am working in an android project where i need to pass an array user[email], user[password] to a web page using json...please if any one can help me width this asap..Thank you!

Comment: Describe ur question in detail....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean. But I guess you need something like this:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(listOfUsers);
String jsonRepresentationForListOfUsers = jsonArray.toString();
```

You can look here for further documentation.

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html